# Entity Framework tried to add user twice and throws user name already taken EntityValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get into MVC with EntityFramework. 
Its going quite well, but there is something i cannot figure out.

I have 3 models, `BierlijstEntry`, `Huis` and `ApplicationUser`.
I have tried to implement the following relations

- `ApplicationUser`  * ... *  `Huis`'s
- `ApplicationUser` 1...* `BierlijstEntry` (`BierlijstEntry` has one `ApplicationUser`)
- `Huis` 1...* `BierlijstEntry` (`BierlijstEntry` has one `Huis`)

  ```
   namespace BierlijstMVC
  {
      public partial class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
      {
      public DatabaseContext()
          : base("DBContext")
      {
      }

      public static DatabaseContext Create()
      {
          return new DatabaseContext();
      }

      public virtual DbSet<BierlijstEntry> BierlijstEntries { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Huis> Huizen { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

          modelBuilder.Entity<Huis>()
              .HasMany(x => x.Users)
              .WithMany(x => x.Huis);

          modelBuilder.Entity<Huis>()
              .HasMany(e => e.BierlijstEntry)
              .WithRequired(e => e.Huis);

          modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
              .HasMany(x => x.BierlijstEntries)
              .WithRequired(x => x.User);
      }
  }
  ```

  }

The models are defined as follows:

**BierlijstEntry**

```
namespace BierlijstMVC.Models
{
    public class BierlijstEntry
    {
        [Key]
        public int BierlijstEntryId { get; set; }

        public int Gedronken { get; set; }
        public int Gehaald { get; set; }

        public int HuisId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual Huis Huis { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Huis**

```
namespace BierlijstMVC.Models
{
    public class Huis
    {
        public Huis()
        {
            Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            BierlijstEntry = new List<BierlijstEntry>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int HuisId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Huisnaam { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BierlijstEntry> BierlijstEntry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
namespace BierlijstMVC.Models
{
    [Table("AspNetUsers")]
    public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Huis = new List<Huis>();
            BierlijstEntries = new List<BierlijstEntry>();
        }

        public string Nickname { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Huis> Huis{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BierlijstEntry> BierlijstEntries { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Nickname", this.Nickname.ToString()));

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
}
```

Now My register gives me three fields: `Email, Password, Nickname (ApplicationUser) and Huisnaam (Huis)`

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Nickname = model.Nickname};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var db = new DatabaseContext();
                    if (!db.Huizen.Any(x => x.Huisnaam.Equals(model.HouseName)))
                    {
                        var huis = new Huis()
                        {
                            Huisnaam = model.HouseName,

                        };
                        BierlijstEntry entry = new BierlijstEntry();
                        entry.Huis = huis;
                        entry.User = user;
                        Huis.BierlijstEntry.Add(entry);
                        Huis.Users.Add(user);
                        user.Huis.Add(huis);
                        user.BierlijstEntries.Add(entry);
                        db.Huizen.AddOrUpdate(huis);
                        db.BierlijstEntries.AddOrUpdate(entry);
                        try
                        {
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                        {
                            ** SNIP: Catch exception
                        }
                    }

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

                    UserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

The first bit of code is the standard creation of a user. The code breaks as soon as it hits `db.SaveChanges()`.

I Assume that due to the relations a user gets added twice. The error I'm getting is that I'm trying adding a user name which already exists. The CreateUser indeed adds it the first time, but SaveChanges for some reason too. HoweverI would not know why and where. I would like some help on this

**Edit**

I do have a `HuisApplicationUser` table in my database, which is mapped as 
`ApplicationUser` * ... * `Huis` but for some reason it is not getting added in that table, but added as a new user

Comment: Can you remove the line, Huis.Users.Add(user);

Answer (score 0):

This line is going to add the same user you already added. 
    Huis.Users.Add(user);

Do you have another table named UserHuis or something similar for the many to many relationship? Depending on what version of asp.net you are using it could be mapped using something similar to this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Huis>()
            .HasMany<Users>(u => u.Users)
            .WithMany(h => h.Huis)
            .Map(hu =>
                    {
                        hu.MapLeftKey("HuisId");
                        hu.MapRightKey("UserId");
                        hu.ToTable("UserHuis");
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I also assumed it was this line. I do have a HuisApplicationUser table but it doesn't add in that table, it just creates a new user

Comment: Are you using EF Core? Unless it was recently changed you have to add a class for the HuisApplicationUser object in EF Core.